# Is there any helpful information in this crash report?

Tags: ios, xcode, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

I am trying to identify the cause of a crash (iOS app), but the symbolicated crash report only points to my main method.

```
8   WxT                               0x00002730 main (main.m:14)
9   WxT                               0x000026e8 start + 32
```

Is there anything here that could help me track down the issue, or is this as useless as it appears to me? What does the "start + 32" tell me?

N.B. my app is WxT, and it only referenced a few times in the report. I've highlighted each occurence with a double asterisk (**).

```
Incident Identifier: 3A6D2AD3-0E9C-41B6-9EA6-4F05EF72B4E0
CrashReporter Key:   2b1b03e6298d7d5bebcb681de363022e7b319df1
Hardware Model:      iPad3,2
**Process:         WxT [3214]**
**Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/613A46E1-5CDC-4A1F-85C5-8D29ACDA289C/WxT.app/WxT**
**Identifier:      WxT**
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-05-23 15:21:02.300 -0500
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  3

Application Specific Information:
**WxT[3214] has active assertions beyond permitted time:** 
{(
    **<SBProcessAssertion: 0x14005c20> identifier: Suspending process: WxT[3214] permittedBackgroundDuration: 10.000000 reason: suspend owner pid:23 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownCPU  preventThrottleDownUI** 
)}

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): -4288.787 (user -4288.787, system 0.000), 100% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.061, 0% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35f83004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35f831fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30b843ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30b830ea __CFRunLoopRun + 818
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30b0649e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30b06366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   GraphicsServices                0x36eca432 GSEventRunModal + 130
7   UIKit                           0x327e6cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
**8   WxT                               0x00002730 main (main.m:14)**
**9   WxT                               0x000026e8 start + 32**

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35f833a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x355f5f04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x355f5c22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35f83004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35f831fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30b843ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30b83124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30b0649e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30b06366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x36523c9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33bf472e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33bf45e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35f83004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35f831fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30b843ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30b83124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30b0649e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30b06366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x35a3dbb2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                      0x35a3da7a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x35ad158a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33bf472e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33bf45e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35f93570 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x30b8863a __CFSocketManager + 726
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33bf472e _pthread_start + 314
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33bf45e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35f83004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35f831fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30b843ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30b83124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30b0649e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30b06366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x3654d0d2 _ZN7WebCoreL15runLoaderThreadEPv + 122
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33bf472e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33bf45e8 thread_start + 0

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Binary Images:
    **0x1000 -    0x2afff +WxT armv7  <d34067e47ac73d7390a27c79ab5582b3> /var/mobile/Applications/613A46E1-5CDC-4A1F-85C5-8D29ACDA289C/WxT.app/WxT**
0x2fee1000 - 0x2ff02fff  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like:

```
Application Specific Information:
**WxT[3214] has active assertions beyond permitted time:** 
{(
    **<SBProcessAssertion: 0x14005c20> identifier: Suspending process: WxT[3214] permittedBackgroundDuration: 10.000000 reason: suspend owner pid:23 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownCPU  preventThrottleDownUI** 
)}
```

the system is trying to move your app to background, and your URL connection (thread.3) is preventing that from happening.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states you tried to run for more than 10 minutes while in the background. By default, iOS apps must stop all processing within 10 minutes upon being put in the background.